# Run tests located in a Rails Engine when mounted in host application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, unit-testing, rails-engines, ruby-on-rails-6.1

I have some tests located in an engine called "Blorgh". I simply test my engine by running the following command in the root directory of my engine's repository.

```
rails test
...
19 runs, 8 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 11 skips
```

Simple. Now, Blorgh is mounted in an app.

```
gem blorgh
```

This app is deployed using a pipeline that includes a test step. I want the test step to execute the mounted engine's tests so that the pipeline stops deployment if it finds a problem with the tests in the Blorgh engine.

The problem is that when `rails test` is executed in the root directory of the host app, it only looks for tests specific to the host app.

```
0 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

How can I execute the tests for my Blorgh engine when it is mounted? I've searched high and low. I'm willing to make my own task by crawling `Blorgh::Engine.root`, but I'm not even sure what `rails test` is doing under the hood.

Comment: I think you're kind of fighting the very nature of why you use engines which is to isolate the development of the engine from the application. If you're using some sort of versioning in the engine and the app is requiring a specific version in its gemfile I can't see why you would actually need this.

Comment: This is not in lieu of testing the engine separately. While the engine has its own pipeline and test step; that won't actively prevent a developer from accidentally pointing to a broken engine version and having that broken engine deployed automatically. The pipelines I am using have no way of consulting the build status of another pipeline. At least not without cobbling together a hack solution.

Comment: say I have `devise` mounted, i don't want to run its tests, but I want to be sure my authentication is working and my "/users/sign_in" page is working, i wouldn't rely on the engine for that, i'd write my own tests in my main app. your engine can brake your app just like any other gem if the main app is not testing for the feature that the engine provides. semantic versioning, breaking changes and all that is the exact tools to mitigate this problem. if the engine is tightly coupled with the main app, just keep versions in sync the same way rails does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set up a rake task to load just the necessary tests. Main app *test* directory should be in your load path, because *test/test_helper.rb* loads the environment:

```rb
# lib/tasks/run_engine_tests.rake

task :run_engine_tests do
  # NOTE: Add main app `test` directory to load path.
  #       This makes requires such as `require "test_helper"`
  #       load main app helper instead of engine helper.
  #       That's what we need to run the tests under our app,
  #       because engine's `test_helper.rb` loads dummy app.
  $LOAD_PATH << Rails.root.join("test").to_s

  # NOTE: Require tests from the engine that you need to run.
  Dir.glob(Blorgh::Engine.root.join("test/**/*_test.rb")).each { |f| require f }
  
  # NOTE: Rails magic does the rest. 
  #       Well, it only executes `Minitest.autorun`
  require "active_support/testing/autorun"
end
```

A quick test:

```sh
$ RAILS_ENV=test bin/rails run_engine_tests
Running 1 tests in a single process (parallelization threshold is 50)
Run options: --seed 12153

# Running:

hello from Blorgh
.

Finished in 0.004990s, 200.4139 runs/s, 200.4139 assertions/s.
1 runs, 1 assertions, 0 failures, 0 errors, 0 skips
```

Use `RAILS_ENV=test`, otherwise, it's loading test environment twice, causing fixtures to load twice as well.

---

*https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.2.3/railties/lib/rails/commands/test/test_command.rb#L29*

*https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/v7.0.2.3/railties/lib/rails/test_unit/runner.rb#L39*